# Add + 1 to LastOrDefault

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm doing an insert form, and I'm trying to create a new PK. I used a `LastOrDefault` method in order to get the last key registered in `DataSource`, and I'm trying to create a new key, but can't find the right syntax. Could you help me please?

```
if (e.CommandName == "InsertItem")
{
   try
   {
       //some other code 
       int idT = int.Parse(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["ID"].ToString()); //find existing ID
       ListagemTimesheet TS = listagembll.GetFileByID(idT); //get current ID

       if (idT== 0) // If ID not exist (==0)
       {
           ListagemTimesheet novo = listagembll.CreateNewID(idtimesheet);

           //create new PK ??

           EditT.Objecto = timesheet; //Bind Insert form
           EditT.Dispose(); //Server clean edit form values
       }
```

Comment: *I'm trying to create a new key,* - generally we let the database do this

Comment: But what to do in my insert method, being that way?

Comment: If you want to create a key in code, use GUID

Comment: I will explore that approach! Thanks

Comment: @T.S. Yeah, but when you think about it, that's just "generate a random number between 1 and 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 and you're virtually guaranteed that it won't collide.." But it's a huge waste of space, bytes wise, when all you want is a unique number

Comment: @CaiusJard ok. We know that DB engine is the best mechanism to generate a unique id for the table. But here is the interesting thing. In several businesses that wasn't good enough. We still needed some identifier that can identify record uniquely independently of what relationship ID and PK/FK was, to promote these changes from one level DB to another **** Anyways, If the ID can't be generated by DB, yea, you can try to select it and try UP it and try save and in multi-threaded system, may be re-try if number is used already by another thread. Or... up it in the separate table via locked SP

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to refer to any `DataSource` or `LastOrDefault`?

Comment: I forget to post it, sry.. It is "CreateNewID method, i done it as a LastOrDefault in BLL back class. GUID is not the right approach, so i'm still with the same problem, i create the edit form properly, but hot to create primary key in the form?